# realitive import inside zipimport python

Tags: python, importerror

I have an application structured like this:

```
|-- main.py
|-- lib.py
|-- scripts.zip
|   |-- run.conf
|   |-- script1.py
|   |-- more scripts...
|   |--
|   |-- base.py
```

main.py imports script1.py, which has a class that inherits from base.py

main.py code:

```
module_name = 'script1'
import zipimport
            importer = zipimport.zipimporter('scripts.zip')  
            if module_name not in sys.modules:
                importer.load_module(module_name)
```

script1.py code:

```
from . import base

class doesstuff(base.scriptbase):

    def __init__:
        pass
```

when main.py tries to import script1.py with zipimport, this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py"
    importer.load_module(module_name)
  File "scripts.zip/script1.py", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

It first I thought it was beacuse zipimport basically puts scripts.zip in the system path, but when I modify script1.py

script1.py code:

```
import base #zip file should be in the system path as a base

class doesstuff(base.scriptbase):

    def __init__:
        pass
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py"
    importer.load_module(module_name)
  File "scripts.zip/script1.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'base'
```

So apparently it isn't quite part of the system path.
so I'm not sure how to have one of the scripts inside the zip file import one of their own. I've tried a couple variations of the above, and pretty much all of them end up with the Systemerror.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to add a `print test` at the end of the file base.py and run it (python base.py). I suspect that there might be an issue there that prevents the module from being loaded

Comment: Nope. Base doesn't get called at all. No output.
If I do 
"importer.load_module('base')"
base loads just fine. and even if I try loading base before script1, it still gives the same error. 
I should also probably mention the above is pesudocode and that I'm running python 3.4.3